# Send email to other user not logged in with action mailer for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email to another user that I am not logged in as and is on another Devise model called 'user2', they use the site differently than 'user'.  When I create a new message I am able to send the current_user an email by doing:

```
UserMailer.new_message_sent_user(current_user).deliver
```

Then in UserMailer:

```
def new_message_sent_user(user)
 @user = user
 mail to: @user.email, subject: "New message sent to user2!"
end
```

However I also need to send an email to 'user2' but am having a hard time finding them by their id and passing their email in to action mailer.  I do know I have a value in user2_id because it is saving successfully on the message create.  In the new action I have a find:

```
@user2 = User2.find(:first,:conditions=>["id = ?", @post.user2_id])
```

Then in create I have

```
UserMailer.new_message_sent_user2(@user2).deliver
```

Then in UserMailer I have:

```
#send to advisor when he has sent a new message to an advisor
def new_message_sent_user2(user2)
     @user2 = user2
     mail to: @user2.email, subject: "You have received a message from user"
end
```

But I am getting an error, I think saying it has a nil email, so how can I find and set the user2 object to send the email?:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update with the create action:

```
# POST /messages
# POST /messages.json
def create

   @message = current_user.messages.build(params[:message])

   respond_to do |format|
   if @message.save

   UserMailer.new_message_sent_user(current_user).deliver
   UserMailer.new_message_sent_user2(@user2)

   format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Your message has been sent!' }
    format.json { render json: @message, status: :created, location: @message }

   else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: can you edit to include to create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question based on the create action you are not creating the @user2 instance for that action. An instance variable does not carry from the new => create action, or edit => update. So all you need to add is

```
@user2 = User2.find(params[:user2_id]) #assuming you have the user2_id as part of the submitted form.
```

I don't know exactly where you are storing the :user2_id in relation to the user, but if it is a has_many/belongs to association it might be easier right after @user is set to set the user2 as well

```
@user2 = @user.user2 #this will return an array of associated user_2's
```

the final action might look like:

```
def create

   @message = current_user.messages.build(params[:message])
   @user2 = User2.find(params[:user2_id]) #or whatever selector

   respond_to do |format|
   if @message.save

   UserMailer.new_message_sent_user(current_user).deliver
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Adam!  Your response spurred me to figure it out!  Using the info you provided and the question from:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337396/rails-couldnt-find-controller-with-id-of   I was able to finally figure it out by putting :  @user2 = User2.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => @message.user2_id})  in the create action!!!  Thank you for your help so much.

Answer (score 0):

check @user2, it seems to be nil.